# Is there a category of markets?

Tags: category-theory, economics

A market is an ill-defined game-theoretic structure where multiple agents negotiate some agreements by wagering some stakes. I have a very open-ended question:

- Is there a good definition of markets as data? Leading to...
- Are there homomorphisms or other structure-preserving maps between markets? Leading to...
- **Is there a category whose objects are markets?**

Comment: Maybe this will be a place to start looking? http://www.gtcenter.org/Archive/2014/Conf/Jimenez1880.pdf